# How do I remove Desclaimer, Terms & Conditions and Sitemap at the bottom of CMS, Product and Category pages?

Tags: magento

I would like to remove Desclaimer, Terms & Conditions and Sitemap at the bottom of CMS, Product and Category pages?

They are considered to be 404 pages from the other pages. Only the Homepage gets connected to the respective page, so I would like to keep them only in the hompage and remove from the rest of the pages in the entire website. Please refer to the below screenshot for clear understanding.

Please help somebody in removing the highlighted part from each and every page of my website except Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea. You can keep them for all pages.
I have a feeling that the links are configured wrongly.
If the footer section comes from a static block then edit that block and change the `href` of the links from `href="link_here"` to `href="{{store url="link_her"}}"`
If the section is rendered by a template then change the hrefs from `href="link_here"` to `href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('link_here')?>"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you think I can find the place to change the things which you have mentioned? I have no clue whether all the CMS, Category and Product pages come from Static or template rendered.

I always created CMS pages by going to CMS and Add new. How do I get to know whether they are from Static or Template Rendered?

Please try telling step by step. I am very, very, very new to this, but would like to do it on my own.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Marius, I found that the footer is not from the static which means it is from the template. Now, please tell me where do I find the template so that I can copy and paste the code which you gave. Also, please double check your code.